# Как лучше убрать повторы в предложении?

Tags: стилистика

Подскажите, как можно убрать повторы в таком контексте: "Некоторые подлоги, не вызывая противоречий в содержании отдельного документа, вызывают несоответствия в системе взаимосвязанной учетной документации"?

Answer (score 1):

Вызывают - служат причиной